# Stating multiple traits with xunit console?

Tags: xunit

I can find nothing concerning what I would consider a rather obvious question.
The xunit.console.clr4 commandline arg help status this:

```
usage: xunit.console.clr4 <xunitProjectFile> [options]
usage: xunit.console.clr4 <assemblyFile> [configFile] [options]

Valid options:
  /silent                : do not output running test count
  /teamcity              : forces TeamCity mode (normally auto-detected)
  /wait                  : wait for input after completion
  /trait "name=value"    : only run tests with matching name/value traits
                         : if specified more than once, acts as an OR operation
  /-trait "name=value"   : do not run tests with matching name/value traits
                         : if specified more than once, acts as an AND operation

Valid options for assemblies only:
  /noshadow              : do not shadow copy assemblies
  /xml <filename>        : output results to Xunit-style XML file
  /html <filename>       : output results to HTML file
  /nunit <filename>      : output results to NUnit-style XML file
```

so it's clear how to format the cl option to specify a single trait rule:

```
/trait "MyTrait=LongTest"
```

but what if I wanted to state multiple traits on the same run? Do I add mulitiple /trait entries, e.g.,

```
/trait "MyTraits=LongTest" /trait "MyTraits=MediumTest"
```

? thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the help states:

```
/trait "name=value"    : only run tests with matching name/value traits
                       : if specified more than once, acts as an OR operation
```

You have to add multiple `/trait` entries.

Comment: Is it somehow possible to make them act as an AND operation?

I have multiple Tests which I only want to run if 2 Traits are active ... For example, my Test has to be "Language=English" and "Type=SelectorTest"